# Can not execute insert query?

Tags: php, mysql

Can you help me solve this problem? im trying to insert data to my database but instead of inserting it die() output; appears

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
        $item_code = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['item_code']);
        $item_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['item_name']);
        $supplier = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['supplier_name']);
        $brand = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['brand_name']);
        $quantity = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['quantity']);
        $unit = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['unit_name']);
        $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['price']);
        $item_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['type_name']);
        $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['cat_name']);

        if ($item_code == '' || $item_name == '' || $supplier == '' || $brand == '' ||
            $quantity == '' ||
            $unit == '' ||
            $price == '' ||
            $item_type == '' ||
            $category == ''
        ) {
            header("Location: item.php?attempt=empty");
        } else {
            $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO itemlist (item_name,supplier_name,brand_name,quantity,unit_name,price,type_name,cat_name)    values('$item_name','$supplier','$brand','$quantity','$unit','$price','$item_type','$category')")

            or die("Could not execute the insert query.");
            header("Location: item.php?attempt=saved");
        }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: check errors `die("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));`

Comment: it will be great to use `mysqli_error($conn)` together with any call to your database in order to handle any errors. try and let us know what is the exact error.

Comment: add " `\`field\` `  " on sql query

Comment: sir Im new to php coding if its okay can you show it?that if you wouldn't mind.thanks

Comment: change `or die("Could not execute the insert query.");` with `or die(mysqli_error($conn));` and let us know is there any error.

Comment: Error description: Field 'item_code' doesn't have a default value

Comment: yes so you have not inserted item_code value please add in insert query

Comment: i think you need to change `||` to `&&` in your if condition

Comment: gotcha. thank you so much

Comment: end line $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "... must have ;

Comment: That must be a long url.

Comment: Now see prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

I just notice things:

- Why use `GET` method to pass data instead of `POST`?
- You can use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) instead of `== ''`
- You can try [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) rather than escaping and sanitizing each submitted data
- What is the purpose of `$_GET['item_code']`? You did not use it in your insert, but it is in your `if()` condition.

Assuming you changed your form from `GET` to `POST` method:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if(empty($_POST['item_code']) || empty($_POST['item_name']) || empty($_POST['supplier_name']) || empty($_POST['brand_name']) || empty($_POST['quantity']) || empty($_POST['unit_name']) || empty($_POST['price']) || empty($_POST['type_name']) || empty($_POST['cat_name'])){

        header("Location: item.php?attempt=empty");

    } else {

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO itemlist (item_code, item_name, supplier_name, brand_name, quantity, unit_name, price, type_name, cat_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $_POST['item_code'], $_POST['item_name'], $_POST['supplier_name'], $_POST['brand_name'], $_POST['quantity'], $_POST['unit_name'], $_POST['price'], $_POST['type_name'], $_POST['cat_name']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        header("Location: item.php?attempt=saved");
    }
}
```

Remember, one empty data will go inside the `if()` condition and execute the `header("Location: item.php?attempt=empty");`.

Answer (score 1):

1)  Add `item_code` in your insert query.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
        $item_code = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['item_code']);
        $item_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['item_name']);
        $supplier = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['supplier_name']);
        $brand = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['brand_name']);
        $quantity = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['quantity']);
        $unit = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['unit_name']);
        $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['price']);
        $item_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['type_name']);
        $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['cat_name']);

        if ($item_code == '' || $item_name == '' || $supplier == '' || $brand == '' ||
            $quantity == '' ||
            $unit == '' ||
            $price == '' ||
            $item_type == '' ||
            $category == ''
        ) {
            header("Location: item.php?attempt=empty");
        } else {
            $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO itemlist (item_code,item_name,supplier_name,brand_name,quantity,unit_name,price,type_name,cat_name)    values('$item_code','$item_name','$supplier','$brand','$quantity','$unit','$price','$item_type','$category')")

            or die("Could not execute the insert query.");
            header("Location: item.php?attempt=saved");
        }
    } 
?>
```

2) Another way to solve it is to define your `item_code` as **`primary key`**.

3) Other way is to define `item_code` with any default value like 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Solution:

```
function escape($col, $conn) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET[$col]);
}

function insert($tbl, $dataArray) {
    foreach ($dataArray as $k => $v) {
        $keys .= $k . ", ";
        $values .= "'" . $this->real_escape_string($v) . "', ";
    }

    $keys = substr($keys, 0, strlen($keys) - 2);
    $values = substr($values, 0, strlen($values) - 2);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $tbl . "(" . $keys . ") VALUES(" . $values . ")";
    $exeq = mysqli_query($sql);
    return $exeq;
}

$fields = array("item_code", "item_name", "supplier_name", "brand_name", "quantity", "unit_name", "price", "type_name", "cat_name");

if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $item_code  = escape('item_code', $conn);
    $item_name  = escape('item_name', $conn);
    $supplier   = escape('supplier_name', $conn);
    $brand      = escape('brand_name', $conn);
    $quantity   = escape('quantity', $conn);
    $unit       = escape('unit_name', $conn);
    $price      = escape('price', $conn);
    $item_type  = escape('type_name', $conn);
    $category   = escape('cat_name', $conn);

    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (!$_GET[$field]) {
            header("Location: item.php?attempt=empty");
        }
    }

    $dataInsert = array(
        'item_code'     => $item_code,
        'item_name'     => $item_name,
        'supplier_name' => $supplier,
        'brand_name'    => $brand,
        'quantity'      => $quantity,
        'unit_name'     => $unit,
        'price'         => $price,
        'type_name'     => $item_type,
        'cat_name'      => $category
    );

    if ( insert("itemlist", $dataInsert) ) {
        header("Location: item.php?attempt=saved");
    } else {
        echo "Could not execute the insert query.";
        exit();
    }  
}
```